# Creating & using indexes - Neo4j 2.0

Tags: neo4j

I have a problem using/creating index in Neo4j.

I'm doing massive insert, so using BatchInserter - import org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserter;

But - after insert, index dont appear ?

I create index like this:

```
BatchInserter inserter = BatchInserters.inserter( DB_CONNECTION_STRING );

Label personLabel = DynamicLabel.label( "Person" );

Label transactionLabel = DynamicLabel.label( "Transaction" );

BatchInserter inserter = inserter.createDeferredSchemaIndex( personLabel ).on( "personid" ).create();

BatchInserter inserter = inserter.createDeferredSchemaIndex( transactionLabel ).on( "txid" ).create();
```

Then, insert the nodes...

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

properties.put( "personid", myPersonID );

long nodeID = inserter.createNode( properties, personLabel );
```

Batch inserter finishes ok.

I have shutdown hook registered, which should complete the batch insert & indexes, right?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
  inserter.shutdown();
} } );
```

Finally, i try Cypher query. However, it reports that index doesn't exist.

```
START n=node:Person(personid='12345')
MATCH (n)-[:MYEDGE]-(x) 
RETURN count(x);
```

Result:

```
STATEMENT_EXECUTION_ERROR: Index `Person` does not exist
```

Any clue??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a schema index during batch insert, while in the Cypher query you use the START clause which uses legacy indexes you'd have to create and update separately.
Try rewriting the query to this:

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[:MYEDGE]-(x) 
WHERE n.persionid='12345' 
RETURN count(x)
```

Cypher will then automatically pick the right index to speed up the query.